# Delete record from grid extjs-4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I can't delete row from my grid.
This calling method from server but going without data.

This is method:

```
deleteUser: function(button) {
        var win   = button.up('window'),
            form   = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord();
        values = form.getValues();

        record.set(values);
        win.close();        

        this.getUsersStore().destroy(record);
        this.getUsersStore().sync();
```

This server method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete(UserInfo data)
        {

            bool success = false;
            string message = "no record found";
            if (data != null && data.Id > 0)
            {
                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    var rec = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == data.Id).
                        FirstOrDefault();
                    rec.Name = data.Name;
                    rec.Email = data.Email;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    success = true;
                    message = "Update method called successfully";
                }
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                data,
                success,
                message
            });
        }
```

UserInfo data - the data come empty.
Inside record i see the data of row. 
From grid this not deleted from DB also.
What i do wrong???

this method is working well:

```
updateUser: function(button) {
        var win    = button.up('window'),
            form   = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();

        record.set(values);
        win.close();
        this.getUsersStore().sync();
    },
```

Comment: It looks like you are pulling the `record` from a Form element, but a store will normally populate a `gridpanel`? Could you perhaps show the code of the `form` element? I would suspect that the `record` you pull out of the form will not refer to anything in the `store`. Also, `destroy` is a method on the `Model` object, not the `Store`.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get the store of your data, you can try `store.remove(record)`

destroy is the direct api configuration option, it's not the function to remove the record from the grid. the correct function name is remove.

```
this.getUsersStore().remove(record);
this.getUsersStore().sync();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this would fit in the code of the OP?